# How to convert a .txt file to a .csv file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv

How do I convert a txt file to a csv file for MATLAB?  Written below is what I have coded and some ideas I have. This isn't suppose to be very long code.

```
    % All data was approved for publication by the USGS.
%SampleData
% Day of Year   Date Number Discharge, cfs
1   37987   4175.512953
2   37988   2065.641026
3   37989   1030.974359
4   37990   674.7589744
5   37991   519.4717949
6   37992   426.5333333
7   37993   389.4974359
8   37994   355.5692308
9   37995   359.5025641
10  37996   558.4461538

function [ ] = convertTexttoCSV(fileNameTxt, fileNameCSV)
data = load('fileNameTxt.txt');%only loads numerical values
 end
```

Would I still need to open and read the txt file after loading it. The text file has some unnecessary string data which is why I used load. Below is what I was planning on using however now I think it was to much for this problem.

```
fid1 = fopen('fileNameTxt.txt','r');%read
fid2 = fopen('fileNameCSV', 'w');%write
%while ~feof(fid1)%go to the end of the line
    % textline = fgetl(fid1);%reads line of text
    %convert to CSV
    % M = [M;str2num(txtline)];%store line of text in an array
    %used for space delimited files
    %  M = dlmread('fileNametxt','delimiter',%[rS cS rE cE])
```

Comment: no idea what your problem is, please rephrase and explain using demo data and desired output

Comment: `importdata(.txt)` -> `csvwrite(.csv)`

Comment: why not do it in bash or cmd?

Comment: Why don't you use `sed` to replace the spaces with commas?... if you want to use the command line terminal.

Comment: @m.s. I added some sample data and rephrased the question. The function should accept an input "fileNameText"that contains the string file name "fileNameCSV" which is the name of the CSV file to create.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Im not familiar with bash or cmd

Answer (score 1):

```
data = importdata('filename.txt');
csvwrite('filename.csv',data.data);
```

this does what you want. `function` way:

```
function [] = txt2csv(txtfile,csvfile)
    data = importdata(txtfile);
    csvwrite(csvfile,data.data);
end
```

I uses `data.data` since `importdata` uses that to separate numeric data from text data, which is stored in `data.textdata`.

Comment: Why did it not work? We can't read your mind and that isn't our job.